# Setting Type of Event or Task via SOAP/REST API

Tags: soap-api, rest-api, describesobject, sobject

I am looking at Object Reference for [Event](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) and [Task](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) sObjects and seeing that both have `Type` and `Subject`. I wanted to use `Type` as one of meeting, call, email and `Subject` as event/task title. But, if I try doing that via API, I get response that:

```
<createResponse>
  <result>
    <errors>
      <fields>Type</fields>
      <message>Event: bad field names on insert/update call: Type</message>
      <statusCode>INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE</statusCode>
    </errors>
    <id xsi:nil=\"true\"/>
    <success>false</success>
  </result>
</createResponse>
```

And looking at sObject description --- I don't see a `Type` field there.

Could someone please confirm, that one shouldn't use `Type` field on both `Task` and `Event` sObjects and instead set type using `Subject` field. In that case, which field one would use for storing email subject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type is a valid field for Activities (Tasks & Events), you can see it in the Task Fields & Event Fields list in setup. However it may not be visible to your user profile, check the Field Level Security settings on the field (*App Setup > Activities > Task Fields : Type* [[Set Field-Level Security]](https://na5.salesforce.com/p/setup/field/StandardFieldAttributes/e?id=Type&type=Task&setupid=TaskFields)).

[image: standard event fields]

Comment: True! `Type` field is 'invisible' on both `Task` and `Event` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [SOAP api developer's guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) the Type field has the following properties:

```
Create, Filter, Nillable, Update
```

so you should be able to change the field. Check the field level security settings for the user you are logged in as.